# Fade out text on horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, fade

I need to create a block with text that fades out on horizontal scroll. This block is on a non-uniform background, so the solution with the addition of a linear gradient on the sides is not suitable.

[text must fade out on scrolling to right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6SWR.png)

Help me adapt this solution or tell me another!

I have found this solution on the internet [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ferfd/ndgLyb2c/86/). Here is realized vertical scroll with the desired effect.

```
<body>
  <div class='fade'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
  </div>
</body>
```

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  color:white;
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/414144/pexels-photo-414144.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260') no-repeat center/cover;
  display: flex;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  
}

.fade{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin:auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    transparent 12%,
    currentColor 30%,
    currentColor 70%,
    transparent 86%
  );
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}

p{
  color:transparent;
}
```

Here is my attempt to adapt this solution to my case [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ferfd/ndgLyb2c/85/). But it is unsuccessful. And I don't understand what exactly I ad doing wrong.

```
<body>
  <div class='fade'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</body>

<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }

  body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    color: white;
    background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/414144/pexels-photo-414144.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260') no-repeat center/cover;
    display: flex;
    background-attachment: fixed;

  }

  .fade {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 540px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,
        transparent 12%,
        currentColor 30%,
        currentColor 70%,
        transparent 86%);
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }


  p {
    color: transparent;
        overflow-x: auto;
        z-index
  }

</style>
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome. What is you question exactly? You seem to have gotten the expected outcome. THe only issue I see is that the beginning of the text is not readable, but that's the same in the example that you shared.

Comment: @KaptainIglo, Hi, thank you! The problem is that I could not adapt the solution and do not understand how to do it. The question is: how can I make such a scroll as I need?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can do what I need. Hope it will help you guys.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/414144/pexels-photo-414144.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260') no-repeat center/cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 80%;
}

.fade {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 12%, currentColor 30%, currentColor 70%, transparent 86%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  width: fit-content;
}

p {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='fade'>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).